# Prove the following set endowed with the binary operation is an abelian group

Tags: group-theory, binary-operations

Let $∗$ be a commutative and associative binary operation
on a set $S$. Assume that for every $x$ and $y$ in $S$, there
exists $z$ in $S$ such that $x ∗ z = y$. Show that this set with the operation $∗$ is an abelian group.
The original question is problem A-2 in the 2012 Putnam Competition which asks to prove that if $a,b,c$ are in $S$ and $a ∗ c = b ∗ c$,
then $a = b$ but I'm interested in why it's an abelian group.
I'd like to see your colorful creative answers, please.

Comment: So you assumed already that $*$ is commutative, so if it is a group it has to be abelian. So are you just asking why $(S, *)$ is a group?

Comment: Can't anyone answer this question and thanks to Andreas for editing it. Well, if no one is going to answer it I guess I have to figure it out for myself then.

Comment: John Ma, yeah, so if we want to prove that, the obvious step is to look for the identity of the set and the inverse of every element of S. But there could be other ways of going about doing that.

Comment: If you assume that $a *c = b*c \Rightarrow a =b$, Then the existence of the identity can be proved easily: Let $x \in S$ and so there is $e\in S$ so that $x*e = x$. Then that assumption can be used to show that $y*e  =y$ for all $y$.

Comment: Hmm, Well I guess I'm an idiot then. So the same argument can be used to find the inverse of element, right? Well whatever, let's just have this question stand for future reference.

Comment: Inverse can be found similarly. But I am not sure why $a*c = b*c \Rightarrow a=b$ is true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32235/discussion-between-john-gally-and-john-ma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to show that

1. there exists the identity element $1_S$
2. for each $x\in S$ there exists the inverse $x^{-1}$

For each $x,y\in S$ let $e_{x,y}\in S$ be such that $x*e_{x,y} = y$, and let $e_x = e_{x,x}$.
For $x\in S$ consider the nonempty set
$$
  E_x := \{e_x\in S: ~x*e_x = x\}
$$
of inverses of $x$ (which are both right and left inverses, in that $*$ is abelian).

The intuition is that $e_x\in E$ should be **the** identity $1_S$, but to prove this we have to show that $E_x = E_y$ for every $y\in S$.

Using associativity and commutativity of $*$,
$$
y*e_x = (x*e_{x,y})*e_x = (x*e_x) * e_{x,y} = x * e_{x,y} = y
$$
which proves that $E_x \subseteq E_y$.
Similarly we can show that the converse inclusion holds and therefore that $E_x=E_y$ for all $x,y$ as expected.
This proves the existence of $1_S$.

As to the inverse, trivially, for $x,1_S\in S$ by hypothesis there exists $z$ s.t. $x*z = 1_S$, and hence such $z$ is $x^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the edit, dude.

Comment: Nice to hear that. If you consider the problem solved you should accept one answer.